# Move items in Ext Js Grid

Tags: extjs, grid

In this sample Ext Js grid:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid.html

You can drag and drop items from one grid to another, but you can't change the order of items in the second grid.

You can drop items back and forth and order them the way you wish, but that's not an elegant way of doing it.

What needs to change in the code so that one can move items up and down on the second grid (the one on right) ?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to make dragGroup and dropGroup have identical values