# How to make POST requests rather than GET requests using proxy model?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using this example in my code, for some reason it sends requests as GET not POST, I don't see that being set anywhere, how do I change it to Post?

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid/infinite-scroll.html

Thanks

Comment: POST should be used for requests which change things on the server, not just for fetching data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generaly jimbojw is right. However you can use `POST` by setting proxy config like this:

```
proxy: {
  type: 'ajax',
  url: 'test.php',
  getMethod: function(request){ return 'POST'; }
  // ...
```

Comment: You seem to be an Ext.Js guru, Would you be kind enough to comment on my other Ext Js question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266123/move-items-in-ext-js-grid

Comment: @user893730, thanks for the guru :). But unfortunately I don't know answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data lives in another domain, and is being included via [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), GET is the only available option.

In order to POST, you either need to be in the same domain so as not to violate the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), or use [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

Having said all that, I don't see anything in the [Ext.data.Store](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-1.1.1/docs/output/Ext.data.Store.html) documentation that specifically talks about the Proxy's methods, and the [Ext.data.DataProxy](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-1.1.1/docs/output/Ext.data.DataProxy.html) documentation isn't much help either.

And, Quentin is generally right, you probably want a GET request anyway since this is more semantically appropriate.  You may be forced to use POST in some circumstances, for example if the amount of data you plan to send to the server is greater than the allowable GET URL length, but generally this shouldn't be an issue.